# Mediaplayer.swf jw player 3.16 not playing in iPad

Tags: ipad, video, jwplayer

We are using mediaplayer.swf (jw player 3.16) in our site to play the videos, but the videos are not playing in iPad, any solution how to play the videos in iPad with existing framework.

Answer (score 3):

Apple portable Products do not support flash player.
Find an alternative to flash.